# ASP .NET C# get all text from a file in the web path

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to open a file that includes some data in a web directory that my C# is running.  Basically just turns it into a string.  I tried doing the following...

```
string email = File.ReadAllText("/orderforms/email_templates/file_to_include.txt");
```

I'm not sure if that is the correct method, but it seems there is a pathing problem, the whole path will change depending what web server it is running on.

This is the directory setup...

```
/Classes/Page.ascx.cs  (the page that tries to read the text from the
file)
/orderforms/<one of multiple pages execute the above class here or in a sub directory
/orderforms/email_templates/file_to_include.txt
/orderforms/email_templates/file_to_include2.txt
```

What path and function should I use to read all of the contents of the file to a string?

Thanks

Comment: FYI, whenever a url-path begins with a slash ("/"), it's interpreted by the application as site ROOT, which means it gets placed immediately after the domain name to build the full URL. This is different from app-root, represented by the "~" character within an asp.net app (server-side). Generally, app-root gets to be the same as site-root (when there are no virtual directories involved), but also in dev environments, generally there ARE virtual dirs involved (when local IIS is used), so you have to be careful with leading slashes.

Comment: My previous comment doesn't relate to your question directly, but I have a feeling you need to know what I said.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

```
string email = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/orderforms/email_templates/file_to_include.txt"))
```

Comment: You have to have the HttpContext to do this, to do it I had to add that. `string email = File.ReadAllText(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/orderforms/email_templates/file_to_include.txt"));`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Server.MapPath:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx